# Efficient Access to One of Many Strings in Configuration File

Tags: android, string, casting, resources

In my app I have numerous strings used to identify a region and location.:

```
<string name="r1s1">Seattle</string>
<string name="r1s2">Des Moines</string>
<string name="r1s3">Bremerton</string>
<string name="r2s1">Tacoma</string>
<string name="r2s2">Burton</string> etc, etc.
```

I can readily access these strings by string name by using a long switch statement:

```
switch(regionCode
{   case 1: sN=getString(R.string.r1s1);break;
    case 2: sN=getString(R.string.r2s1);break;  etc etc
```

I want to calculate this string name and use it to access the string more directly:

```
stationNameKey="r"+regionCode+"s"+stationCode;// e. g. r1s1
stationName=getString(R.string.stationNameKey);
```

This second statement is not correct and will not compile here is the message:

```
! compiler error:: stationNameKey cannot be resolved or is not a field.
```

I assume a cast from String to Resource Name Identifier would work but cannot find it.

Q: How do I cast a string to make my second statement work correctly. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Resources.getIdentifier()
see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and [this](http://www.anddev.org/tinytut_-_get_resources_by_name__getidentifier_-t460.html)

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(stationNameKey,"string",null);
```

should work to get the id you need

Comment: @Lucia, Your solution worked for me. Thank you!.  I only had to add my package name for the third parameter. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this that way. The resource names are used at compile time to generate resource numbers. `R.string.xxx` is actually a number.

What you can do is to use parallel string array resources, which you create in res/values/strings.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="region_keys">
        <item>r1s1</item>
        <item>r1s2</item>
        <item>r1s3</item>
        <item>r2s1</item>
        <item>...</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="region_values">
        <item>Seattle</item>
        <item>Des Moines</item>
        <item>Bremerton</item>
        <item>Tacoma</item>
        <item>...</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

In code, do this:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] regionKeys = res.getStringArray(R.array.region_keys);
String[] regionValues = res.getStringArray(R.array.region_values);

// Create a hash map of key/value pairs
HashMap<String, String> regions = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (int i = 0; i < regionKeys.length; i++) {
    regions.put(regionKeys[i], regionValues[i]);
}
```

Now you can reference your strings from the map `regions`, like this:

```
String key = 'r1s1';
String regionString = regions.get(key);
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough and informative solution. I appreciate it and will keep it in mind for future projects, how I know how the hash map works.  I have chosen the solution shown below for my project, it fits in very well to the existing code.